# How to configure squid-cache for this Payload?

Tags: linux, http, squid, payload

I've got a problem with Squid-cache config and this payload connecting with HTTP Injector:

```
CONNECT [host_port][split][lf]PUT /? HTTP/1.1[lf]Host: subdomain.host.com[lf]
```

The problem is that when I try to connect, I get 400 bad status. This seems to happen only with my VPS's squid-cache because if I try to use the same payload with fastssh(.)com (or even with my VPS's SSH + external proxy) it works perfectly.

I tried everything and I've noticed that the problem is the [lf] before PUT. If I delete it, the payload connects OK, but 
unfortunately I need that [lf].

Hope anyone could help me to configure squid for this payload, im really stuck.

What already tried?

- Enable safe_ports and ssl_ports for SHH (port 22)
- An "on_unsuported_protocol" rule allowing tunneling for squid_error "ERR_PROTOCOL_UNKNOWN"
- Recompile squid with "enable-http-violations"
- Allow PUT method

Regards